# Cant find any possible errors but Java says different

Tags: java

I've got a problem, I'm programming in Java and when I went to run it, It came up with a list of about 6 errors. These

```
Exception in thread "Display" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 64
    at com.cmnatic.mld.graphics.Screen.clear(Screen.java:27)
    at com.cmnatic.mld.Game.render(Game.java:107)
    at com.cmnatic.mld.Game.run(Game.java:77)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If it helps, here is my code (ofc it does)

Game.java:

```
package com.cmnatic.mld;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.cmnatic.mld.graphics.Screen;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static int width = 300; // 300 * 3 = 900
    public static int height = width / 16 * 9; //168.75 * 3 = 506.25
    public static int scale = 3;
    public static String title = "CMNatic's MLD Entry #49";


    private Thread thread;
    private JFrame frame;
    private boolean running = false;

    private Screen screen;

    private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    private int[] pixels =((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

    public Game() {
        Dimension size = new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale);
        setPrefferedSize(size);

        screen = new Screen(width, height);

        frame = new JFrame();
        this.setSize(900,506); 
    }

    private void setPrefferedSize(Dimension size) {

    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this , "Display");
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        running = false;
        try {
        thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final double ns = 100000000.0 / 60.0; // nano-seconds = 1000000000 (9 0'S) / 60.0
        double delta = 0;
        int frames = 0;
        int updates = 0;
        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now-lastTime) / ns;  //nano-seconds (ns)  
            lastTime = now;
            while (delta >= 1) {
                update();
                updates++;
                delta--;
            }
            render();
            frames++;

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println(updates + " ups, " + frames + " fps");
                frame.setTitle(title + "    |    " + updates + "ups, " + frames);
                updates = 0;
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    int x = 0, y = 0;

    public void update() {
        y++;
        if (y % 10 == 0) x++;
        x++;
        //y++;
    }

    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {   
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
```

Screen.Java

```
package com.cmnatic.mld.graphics;

import java.util.Random;

public class Screen {

    private int width, height;
    public int[] pixels;
    public final int MAP_SIZE = 8;
    public final int MAP_SIZE_MASK = MAP_SIZE - 1;
    public int[] tiles = new int[MAP_SIZE * MAP_SIZE];

    private Random random = new Random();

    public Screen(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        pixels = new int[width * height]; // 50,400

        for (int i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE * MAP_SIZE; i++) {
            tiles[i] = random.nextInt(0xffffff);
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            tiles[i] = random.nextInt(0xffffff);
            tiles[0] = 0;   
        }
    }

    public void render(int xOffset, int yOffset) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            int yy = y + yOffset;
            //if (yy < 0 || y >= height) break;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                int xx = x + xOffset;
                //if (xx < 0 || x >= width) break;
                int tileIndex = ((xx >> 4) + xOffset& MAP_SIZE_MASK) + ((yy >> 4)& MAP_SIZE_MASK) * MAP_SIZE;   
                pixels[x + y * width] = tiles[tileIndex];   


            }
        }
    }

}
```

If anyone could help, I would be forever grateful!

Comment: Format your stack trace (good for including it) and specify which line(s) it refers to.

Comment: Screen.java--- line 27

Comment: It would help if you annotated the stack trace lines in your posted source so we didn't have to count lines.

Comment: @Nambari It's good etiquette not to make SO answerers dig through the code.

Comment: Why do you use pixels.length and access tiles array in the for loop?

        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            tiles[i] = random.nextInt(0xffffff);
            tiles[0] = 0;

Comment: @chrylis: It is comment, not answer. I didn't tell what is wrong, I just commented which line to check.

Comment: @Nambari The line number was posted with the stack trace. My comment was to ask the OP to mark in the code which line was 27.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I didn't intentionally not put where it was referring to.

Comment: Unrelated: Consider using `height = width * 9 / 16` or `height = (int)(width / 16.0 * 9.0)` instead of `height = width / 16 * 9` in `Game`. The `/` and `*` are evaluated left-to-right and remain integers when both arguments are integers and you will lose precision (first `width/16` is evaluated as an integer then that is multiplied by `9`). `300/16*9` is 162, but `300*9/16` is 168 which is closer to the actual value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Screen.clear()` you have:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        tiles[i] = random.nextInt(0xffffff);
        tiles[0] = 0;   
    }
```

But based on your comments, `pixels` is clearly larger than `tiles`. You probably meant `tiles.length` in that for loop (I'm presuming `clear` is supposed to be doing the same thing you are doing in that loop at the end of the `Screen` constructor).

In general, when you see an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, it precisely means that an array index is out of bounds. When you run into that, look carefully at your code and try to find any opportunities for that to happen. In this case, the use of a different array's `length` in the index loop is a big red flag.

Also, incidentally, the `tiles[0] = 0` in that loop looks like it isn't supposed to be there.

Comment: Thanks dude! Worked like a charm, that was a foolish mistake :P

Comment: Not foolish. It's good to have other people look at code that you've been staring at for too long.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're using `pixels` and `tiles` interchangeably in your `clear` method. The logical "board" size is 8x8, but your `pixels` array is sized based on the passed-in parameters. You then try to iterate over the 50k or so pixels in the 8x8 board and promptly run off the end.

Additionally, both of those arrays are very obviously representing two-dimensional concepts (a board and a screen), and it makes your code much clearer to use a two-dimensional array:

```
int pixels[][] = new int[width][height];
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, fortunately Jason's answer worked for me. But I'm scanning my code for little things like that :)

Thanks again